# Handling slashes on URL parameters

Tags: php, symfony, twig, url-routing, urlencode

I'm running into some issues trying to guess how to handle URLs with parameters on Symfony+Twig.

I have this route:

```
<route id="artist.front" path="/artist/{kw}/">
<default key="_controller">App\Web\Controllers\Front::homePage</default>
</route>
```

And this code on the Twig template:

```
{% autoescape false %}
<a href="{{ path('artist.front',{'kw':a.urlkeyword|url_encode} )}}">{{ a.name }}</a>
{% endautoescape %}
```

`urlkeyword` parameter is passed as is (i.e. not URL encoded previously) both on the entity constructor and on its getter (getURLKeyword).

However, when rendering the template I get this HTML code:

```
<a href="/index.php/artist/AC%252FDC/">AC/DC</a>
```

(If I remove the url_encode from the template Twig throws an error calling path()).

The target controller has this code:

```
public function artistPage($kw)
{
    $decoded = urldecode($kw);
    $this->log->info("kw:      {$kw}");
    $this->log->info("decoded: {$decoded}");
}
```

and echoes:

```
kw:      AC%2FDC 
decoded: AC/DC
```

so I think the kw is read correctly from the controller, but I understand the URL should be encoded as AC%2FDC instead on the final HTML code on the first place: The URLEncoded string is encoded twice.

Is AC%2FDC the correct encoding, or is it necessary to use the double encoding (AC%252FDC) in Symfony? And, if it is possible to use the first (correct) URL encoding, what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
<route id="artist.front" path="/artist/{kw}/">
    <default key="_controller">App\Web\Controllers\Front::homePage</default>
    <requirement key="kw">.+</requirement>
</route>
```

And remove the url encoding/decoding.

Comment: Thank you for your response. However, removing the encoding/decoding makes the linked URL /index.php/artist/AC/DC/ (i.e. slashes are not encoded at all), so the {kw} can conflict with other parts of the route path.

For example, if I later add a new route for "/artist/{kw}/info" and I have a kw like "something/info", artist.front become "/artist/something/info" (i.e. kw not encoded at all)  which conflicts with the "/artist/{kw}/info" page with kw=something. I think the generated URL should be in this example "/artist/something%2finfo/info" (with kw part URLencoded).