# Encoding parameters in Symfony path twig function

Tags: php, twig, symfony3.x

In my application, I'm using the Symfony Twig extension function [`path`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/twig_reference.html#path) to create a link to another route. That route accepts a parameter, so I wrote my path function like this:

```
<a href="{{ path('r', {p: p}) }}">...</a>
```

In some cases, the given value `p` contains a slash and Symfony fails with the error:

> "Parameter "p" for route "r" must match "[^/]++" (".../..." given) to generate a corresponding URL.")

I would expect Symfony to deal with this and automatically URL encode these values, but apparently not (or I'm doing something wrong).

Anyway, I managed to fix that with the [`url_encode`](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/url_encode.html) Twig filter, like so:

```
<a href="{{ path('r', {p: p|url_encode}) }}">...</a>
```

Now in my controller, I accept this parameter like so:

```
/**
 * @Route("/a/b/{p}", name="r")
 **/
public function someAction($p) {
   // ...
}
```

And apparently Symfony does not automatically URL decode this value `$p`, which I'd expect as well.

Am I doing something wrong here, or is it really necessary to handle URL encoding/decoding yourself? In the Symfony docs I don't find any details about this at all.

Comment: Have you seen this question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31331489/symfony-handling-slashes-on-url-parameters

Comment: That's it, thanks @MohamedBenHENDA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently the default parameter restrictions don't allow forward slashes. After "loosening" them it worked:

```
/**
 * @Route("/a/b/{p}", name="r", requirements={"diagramResourceId"=".+"})
 **/
public function someAction($p) {
   // ...
}
```